# Issue executing Github Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems, github-actions, github-cli

I have an Android Studio project connected to GitHub Actions, but my GitHub actions started to fail and I don't know the reason. For example, the log of working actions was:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
31
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
32
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0
33
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/build_info
34
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/cache
35
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/doc
36
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/extensions
37
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems
38
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/plugins
39
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/specifications
40
Fetching bundler 2.2.29
41
Installing bundler 2.2.29
```

But now for some reason I'm seeing this and builds fail:

```
Fetching bundler 2.2.29
32
Retrying download gem from https://rubygems.org/ due to error (2/4): Bundler::PermissionError There was an error while trying to write to `/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/cache/bundler-2.2.29.gem`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
33

34
Retrying download gem from https://rubygems.org/ due to error (3/4): Bundler::PermissionError There was an error while trying to write to `/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/cache/bundler-2.2.29.gem`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
35

36
Retrying download gem from https://rubygems.org/ due to error (4/4): Bundler::PermissionError There was an error while trying to write to `/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/cache/bundler-2.2.29.gem`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
```

Telling me that I need to grant permission. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear how Android project is related to Ruby gems? Do you use some Ruby tools for android project? Also it would be helpful to share your workflow file.

Comment: Are you using the hosted runners? Which OS? Any change you have checked in the gem folder in the repo?

Comment: Pls check if [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76301400/2748255) applies