# Error: Command failed with exit code 23: bundle install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify

I am new in shopfy development. I follow the instruction for shopify theme customization - https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/getting-started/customize

When I run `shopify theme dev` then an error happens in terminal.

```
osama@debian:~/works/shopify-dev/OsamaTheme$ shopify theme dev
Error: Command failed with exit code 23: bundle install
There was an error while trying to write to `/usr/lib/node_modules/@shopify/theme/node_modules/@shopify/cli-kit/assets/cli-ruby/Gemfile.lock`. It is likely that you need
to grant write permissions for that path.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.3.3
```

When I run `shopify theme dev` it should open a preview mode.

My environment details-

```
THEME CONFIGURATION                
Store                  <STORE_NAME>.myshopify.com
Development Theme ID   #1.........8

TOOLING AND SYSTEM                 
Shopify CLI    3.44.1
OS             linux-amd64
Shell          /bin/bash
Node version   v19.8.1
Ruby version   3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with sudo or change permission with `sudo chown -R`. I had similar problem and I am using debian system - sudo helped `sudo shopify theme dev --store`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and, after reading [Bundler troubleshooting docs](https://bundler.io/doc/troubleshooting.html), I found out the problem was I had some Bundler versions installed from Gems as regular user. Hopefully (I didn't check before solving), `bundle install` was using one of them.

```
# This doesn't tell whether each package is installed as root or regular user
gem list bundler
bundler (2.4.10, 2.4.7, 2.3.26, 2.3.5, default: 2.2.22)

dpkg -l bundler
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Nome           Versão       Arquitectura Descrição
+++-==============-============-============-====================================
ii  bundler        2.3.5-2      all          Manage Ruby application dependencies
```

My solution was to uninstall all Bundler gems, leaving only the OS provided one

```
sudo gem uninstall bundler
Select gem to uninstall:
 ...
 4. All versions
> 4
```

After this, running `bundle install` asked for my password and successfully installed all gems thru `sudo`:

```
bundle install
Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  ...enter your password and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.
  Password:       
...
Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 173 gems now installed.
```

### Do not run Bundler with `sudo`

Bundler does some actions as root, and some others as regular user. It asks for your sudoer password (if you're a sudoer) to run root actions as root. If you do `sudo bundle install`, it does **all** actions as root, including network ones. This is a obvious vunlerability. Besides, it creates root-owned files where they shouldn't, making you unable to do further actions as a regular user. So follow advice from [Bundler man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bundle-install.1.html#sudo%20usage): "You  should  never  use sudo bundle install".

### Do not change system directory permissions

They're there for a reason. Opening them means creating vulnerable spots no one should want. So we better leave them as they are and solve point issues where they are.